# With the new Vulkan dynamic rendering, how to clear attachments outside of CmdBeginRendering?

Tags: dynamic, attachment, vulkan

It is sometimes necessary to clear part or all of an attachment during a rendering sequence.

Render passes and frame buffers had an array of attachments identified by index.
CmdClearAttachments was used to clear a rectangle during rendering.
CmdClearColorImage and CmdClearDepthStencilImage also exist, but these are used outside render passes and also don't support rectangle clearing.

What is the equivalent operation with dynamic rendering?

Comment: The spec is unclear on this topic (in my opinion).
I think you can go with vkCmdClearAttachments and assume attachments are ordered in the same order that you provided them in the VkRenderingInfo structure you used to begin the rendering (colors attachments first, then depth and finaly stencil).
Anyway if you find a valid anwser, don't hesitate to post it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic rendering's `vkCmdBeginRendering` creates a render pass instance, which has a sequence of attachments. `vkCmdClearAttachments` clears attachments of a render pass instance.

Dynamic rendering is not a different kind of rendering; it's just a shortcut to what already exists.

Comment: The documentation is just not clear. as Siliace suggests, I'm now assuming Depth/Stencil follow Color attachments in logical index order.  Even the documentation for `VkClearAttachment` calls structure member `colorAttachment` though it was an index into all classic frame buffer attachments.

Comment: @Greg: It says, "*it is an index into the currently bound color attachments*" You *have* "bound color attachments" in direct rendering. Again, direct rendering *is a render pass*, and it has *all* of the constructs therein. It has attachments, both color and otherwise.

Comment: @Greg: "*I'm now assuming Depth/Stencil follow Color attachments in logical index order.*" That's not how it works. When clearing the depth/stencil, you specify the depth/stencil for the aspect mask. The `colorAttachment` index is irrelevant. Again, this works *exactly* like regular render pass rendering because dynamic rendering *is a render pass*.